# On/Off Darkmode Button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, switch-statement

I can click it once but after that, it is stuck on Darkmode and I can't switch back

```
public static bool i = false;

private void BtnDark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = true;

    if (i == true) // Darkmode
    {
        //...
        i = false;
    }
    else if (i == false) // Whitemode
    {
        //...
        i = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You always set `i = true;` at the beginning of your click handler. So of course it will never enter the `else` part because the `if` condition is always true. (Btw: note that `if (i == true)` is the same as `if (i)` and `if (i == false)` is better written as `if (!i)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are always setting `i = true` in the beginning of the Method. This variable should be defined outside of the method (and you should give it a proper name)

```
public static bool i = false;
private void BtnDark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //i = true;  JUST REMOVE THIS LINE
    if (i) // Darkmode
    {
        //...
        i = false;
    }
    else // Whitemode
    {
        //...
        i = true;
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
if (i = !i)    //assign and compare at the same time
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Where do you change the `i` though? From the question this seems to want a toggle functionality.

Comment: @panoskarajohn look inside `if` and `else`

Comment: Oh ok i see. Yes this works as well.